# Newbie Python: Print Function that Outputs NULL bytes

Tags: python, printing

I don't program in Python at all, so please forgive my code. I am trying to write a print function that terminates after a certain number of bytes. This is what I have done so far:

```
   def print_stuff(stuff, size):
    i = 0
    data = ""
    while i < size:
            if stuff[i]=='\0':
                    data += " "
            else:
                    data += stuff[i]
    print data
```

But when I tried to do printf_stuff(data, 5050) Python doesn't print anything and seems to freeze. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not incrementing the value in `i`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a string slice and a replace.

```
def print_stuff(stuff, size):
    data = stuff[:size]             # Slice it up to the size that you want.
    data = data.replace('\0', ' ')  # Replace all occurrences of \0 with a space.
    print data
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you need to put i += 1 in there probably after your condition statements:

```
def print_stuff(stuff, size):
  i = 0
  data = ""
  while i < size:
    if stuff[i]=='\0':
      data += " "
    else:
      data += stuff[i]
    i += 1                        # Here's your missing line.
  print data
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing `i` variable